# Where should I place my bash setup files when using docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile is below.
Currently I copy the dotfiles (which are referenced within the .bashrc) to /root
Is there a better way to organize them?

```
FROM alpine:latest
LABEL maintainer="Michael Durrant<junk@snap2web.com>"
RUN apk add bash git vim
COPY alpine_bashrc /root/.bashrc
COPY .bash_functions.sh /root
COPY .bash_aliases /root
COPY .git-completion.bash /root
RUN "/bin/bash"
```

Comment: What are you planning to do with the container, such that having a root shell with involved dotfiles is important, and you won't mind when the container is deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having 1 `COPY` directive for each file, it might be advisable to have a directory instead.  The limitation would be that the files must be named as they would appear in the container.

```
$ ls .
    Dockerfile
    dotfiles/
      .bashrc
      .git-completion.bash
      .bash_functions.sh
      .bash_aliases.sh
```

### Dockerfile

```
...
COPY dotfiles/ root/
```

Each of those `COPY` directives creates a new layer in your container.  Save space/time by having one directive.